# Signal event completion asynchrounously after a POST request to a view page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, controller

I have a ASP.NET MVC application which has a view populated with a model which needs to retrieve some data from the user. Besides that, I also have a hidden **div** tag which contains more information but it should be visible only after the model was sent to the controller on a POST request and after it has processed the information from the model it should change the **div** tag to visible. Is some way to signal the view that the request was processed and render visible the **div** tag, remaining on the same page. I believe this is similar to a partial postback from ASP.NET.

Thanks,
Tamash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's possible via some AJAX functionality. I'm using jQuery in my example:

```
$.post('Controller/Action', $('#formId').serialize(), function() {
  $('#yourDiv').show();
});
```

This uses jQuery to post the data contained in a form with the HTML id 'formId' to a URL 'Contoller/Action' and shows the div with id 'yourDiv' in case the AJAX request finished successfully. The call $('#formId').serialize encodes the form elements in HTML form with id formId for submission in the AJAX request.

More on jQuery and AJAX [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)

Comment: I have tried that but the POST request is triggered not by the ajax call, but by the default MVC mechanism. How could I impose that?

Comment: Put a javascript event handler on the triggering submit button and prevent default behavior in javascript code.

Comment: I did set the onclick event of the button to the ajax function, but how can I prevent the default mechanism?

Comment: Here is a blog post that shows a complete example on how to submit a form via ajax: http://www.queness.com/post/160/create-a-ajax-based-form-submission-with-jquery and here is the jQuery documentation link http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/